# why does num_boost_round in xgboost influence auc score? it is crazy

Tags: boosting

I tried to do xgboost native cv function and found that the auc score depends on num_boost_round parameter of cv function. When num_boost_round increases auc score also increases! Why is that?
What is the optimal value of num_boost_round and why?

Comment: Using bayesean reasoning: since many, many people use XGboost every day, the prior that there is such a fundamental error is extremely low.  One person having issues with a model in XGboost is a small amount of evidence, so the posterior says there is very little chance there is an error in XGboost, and a very large chance there is something you just dont understand about the library, or your data.  Please be more skeptical of yourself, and don't throw around weighty accusations like "it seems like there is an error in XGboost", it's a good way to not be taken seriously.

Answer (score 1):

I was confused because n_estimators parameter in python version of xgboost is just num_boost_round. First I trained model with low num_boost_round and than I increased it, so the number of trees boosted the auc. 
The optimal value is the number of iteration cv function makes with early stopping enabled.

Comment: Was this intended as an answer to your question, or a bit of  
new information to help potential answerers? Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide 
answers to the original question. If you want to add more information, use the gray [edit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/276696/edit) below the question body.